# python - AttributeError: 'MainFrame' object has no attribute 'm_textCtrl2'

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm trying like this

```
import wx
import gui
from xml.dom.minidom import parse

class MainFrame(gui.MainFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        dom = parse("data.xml")
        data = dom.getElementById("album")
        self.m_textCtrl2.SetValue(data)
```

I have defined m_textCrtl2 in gui and this is main init

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    mainFrame = MainFrame(None)
    app.SetTopWindow(mainFrame)
    mainFrame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

and traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CDBase.py", line 40, in <module>
    mainFrame = MainFrame(None)
  File "CDBase.py", line 16, in __init__
    self.m_textCtrl2.SetValue(data)
AttributeError: 'MainFrame' object has no attribute 'm_textCtrl2'
```

I'm newbie with python, so I will be grateful for any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MainFrame(gui.MainFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        dom = parse("data.xml")
        data = dom.getElementById("album")
        self.m_textCtrl2.SetValue(data)
```

You didn't call the superclass's constructor. You need to call it explicitly.

```
class MainFrame(gui.MainFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MainFrame, self).__init__(whatever, arguments, but, not, self)
        dom = parse("data.xml")
        data = dom.getElementById("album")
        self.m_textCtrl2.SetValue(data)
```